# AppEngine development environment gives java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I'm getting the following error when I run my app on Eclipse development environment, but when I deploy app to app-engine it works fine. Is it possible to get this work in development environment?

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /my-controller/. Reason:

    (class: org/datanucleus/TransactionImpl, method: internalPreRollback signature: ()V) Accessing value from uninitialized register 5

Caused by:

java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/datanucleus/TransactionImpl, method: internalPreRollback signature: ()V) Accessing value from uninitialized register 5
 at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.<init>(ObjectManagerImpl.java:283)
 at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.<init>(JDOPersistenceManager.java:132)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.<init>(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.java:42)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory.newPM(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:77)
 at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:578)
 at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:557)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have asm (asm.ow2.org) and/or cglib (cglib.sourceforge.net) in your build path ?
If so remove them.